# Finding the most likely serve speed of a tennis player

Tags: statistics, median

> U.S. Open Tennis Championship a statistician keeps track of every serve that player hits.  The statistician reported that the mean serve speed of a particular player was 95 miles per hour. Suppose that the statistician indicated that the serve speed distribution was skewed to the left.  Which of the following values is most likely the value of the median serve speed.
>
> A) 77 mph
>
> B) 95 mph
>
> C) 86 mph
>
> D) 104 mph

Comment: Note that a bunch "outlieers" (with respect to normal distribution, say) don't influence the median, but they "pull" the mean.

Answer (score 1):

When a distribution is skewed left, this means that we have outliers in the lower end of the range of values.

These don't influence the median as much, but this affects the mean greatly. Median is more heavily dependent on the frequencies of numbers, not the actual values of those numbers.

Therefore, the mean will be less than the median in a left-skewed distribution.

The only answer choice that fits here is D.

Here is a diagram to help you visualize the expected result:

[image: distributions statistics]